# Rails app call APIs using proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, proxy

I have subscribed to an API service which provides access based on static IP (For both Live and Testing).

Since my development area ISP doesn't provide a static IP, I have enabled API access to my staging machine IP, which is static. I installed squid and enabled/setup a proxy server in my staging server so that I can use it as a proxy and make calls to the API while i do development.

I am using Mac for my development and Networking>Proxy settings wont work for system wide( Terminal ). Due to this, I was using Trial versions of MacProxy, proxifier( proxy clients) and all was was working fine till trial expired. Are there any free alternatives to this for Mac?

I tried to setup proxy by creating ssh socks proxy and setting http_proxy="xxx". In terminal. When I check terminal IP post setting using *curl ipecho.net/plain ; echo*, it shows proper IPs but when I run local rails development server and tries to access the API, its rejecting call with invalid IP (it shows non proxied IP)

Comment: How are you connecting to the API services? Are you using net/http library?

Comment: I am actually trying to use a Gem ( hotel_beds ) to connect to API, which internally uses Savon gem to use http connection. I am assuming savon implemented on top of net/http.

Answer (score 0):

An free alternative that might solve your problem might be a project on github:

> **[sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle)** ([read me](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/blob/master/README.md))

It forwards `TCP` and `DNS` requests a remote ssh server.

The most basic use of sshuttle looks like this:

```
./sshuttle -r username@sshserver 0.0.0.0/0 -vv
```

To tunnel all traffic you might do:

```
./sshuttle --dns -vr ssh_server 0/0
```

There are also helper functions available [here](https://github.com/teohm/dotfiles/blob/master/public/.functions.d/sshuttle.bash), which can simpify some of the commands.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but oresent sshuttle wont work with Yosemite. Will try this post they fix the issue with ipfw.

Answer (score 0):

The system level proxy settings aren't used by ruby applications. Typically this is a code level option passed to the library you are using to make connections.

If you want Savon to use a proxy then you need to pass this to Savon when you create the client:

```
client = Savon.client(proxy: "http://example.org", ...)
```

If this call is being made inside a gem, then unless that gem already provides that option then you would need to fork it to add the option

The gem you mention seems to already implement this - it's [configuration](https://github.com/platformq/hotel_beds/blob/master/lib/hotel_beds/configuration.rb) class has a proxy attribute that seems to be passed through to savon.

Comment: I tried this but it seems to be broken. Since I was more occupied with my own app development, thought if there is any easy way to setup proxy for rails app( which is free. Macports, Proxifier etc are paid but works), could have been little better and also can be reused for 'wider audience', who wants to run any rails app behind a proxy server regardless hassles of checking net/http or gems implementation. I will try forking it as you mentioned and try to fix it.